# How to add a tag where there isn't one yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have this HTML code for example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.
```

How can I add tag `<p></p>` for every text where I do not have any tags, like this untagged lorem ipsum text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your full text/lipsum is wrapped in some `div` or other `html` tag:

```
<div class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

You can find the paragraphs, split by new lines, then re-insert it with surrounding p tags.

```
const element = $('.text')
const content = element.html()
const lines = content.split('\n')
const paragraphs = lines.filter(x => x)
const html = paragraphs.map(x => '<p>' + x + '</p>').join()
element.html(html)
```

If you're unfamiliar with fat arrows (x => ...) let me know and I'll change it to JS5

https://jsfiddle.net/wtLs7ef6/2/

Comment: Thanks @Pottor, this will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the paragraphs and build a new node for every paragraph. Then append to `document.body`.

```js
var text = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'];

text.forEach(function (t) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```